# Comparing two objects through a boolean method, within my car class

Tags: java, if-statement, methods, boolean, compare

I am having trouble writing my main method within my car class. My class code is written as following;

```
public boolean compare (Car otherCar) {
    return (model.equals(otherCar.model) && year == otherCar.year);
}
```

My problem is i am having trouble writing my main method i need to compare my "ferrari" car object with my "cobra" car object. I need to use an if/else statement and the method compare to compare the ferrari obj with the
cobra obj. And need to output "Same" if they are the same, or "Different" if they are different. All my other methods have been working fine besides this one.

Edit:

```
private String model;
private int year;

// default constructor
public Car()
{
    model = "NA";
    year = 0;
}

// overloaded constructor
public Car (String newModel, int newYear)
{
    model = newModel; 
    year = newYear;
}

// mutator methods
public void setModel (String newModel)
{
    model = newModel;
}

public void setYear (int newYear)
{
    year = newYear;
}

// accessor methods
public String getModel()
{
    return model;
}

public int getYear()
{
    return year;
}

public boolean compare (Car otherCar)
{
    return (model.equals(otherCar.model) && year == otherCar.year);
} 

public void print()
{
    System.out.println(model + " (" + year + ")");
}
}
```

My question is how should i write the if - else statement in my main method to compare these two objects using the compare method

Edit 2:`  {
         // Create an object of the class Car named ferrari
         Car ferrari = new Car();

```
     // Use the print method to print all information about the ferrari object.
     ferrari.setModel("Ferrari");
     ferrari.setYear(2010);
     ferrari.print();
     // Create an object of the class Car named cobra, passing parameters "Cobra" and 1967.
     Car cobra = new Car("Cobra", 1967);

     // Print information about the Cobra object using get methods.
     System.out.println(cobra.getModel() + " " + cobra.getYear());

     // Change the model of the cobra object to "Shelby Cobra".
     cobra.setModel("Shelby Cobra");

     // Change the year of the cobra object to 1963.
     cobra.setYear(1963);


     System.out.println(cobra.getModel() + " " + cobra.getYear());

     // Use an if/else statement and the compare method to compare the ferrari obj with the
```

`

Comment: Where and how have you declared model and year in your method? Can you share more code?

Comment: Yes just posted an edit of my car class. Would you like to see what i have written in my main method as well?

Comment: Please re-edit and pay close attention to the documentation (and preview) for code formatting.

Comment: Maybe you should also show where you declare and compare your objects

Comment: just made an edit with all my code involved i could really use any advice even if it is not 100 percent going to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your main method, you can simply write an if else for comparing cars and printing out like this,

```
if (ferrari.compare(cobra)) {
    System.out.println("Both cars are same.");
} else {
    System.out.println("Both cars are different.");
}
```

Another note, for printing objects values, you should better override toString() method that way you don't need to implement your print() method like you did. You can implement toString method like this,

```
public String toString() {
    return String.format("model: %s, year: %s", model, year);
}
```

And then your if else can be written like this and will look better,

```
    if (ferrari.compare(cobra)) {
        System.out.println("("+ferrari + ") AND (" + cobra + ") cars are same");
    } else {
        System.out.println("("+ferrari + ") AND (" + cobra + ") cars are different");
    }
```

Which will give following output,

```
(model: Ferrari, year: 2010) AND (model: Shelby Cobra, year: 1963) cars are different
```